# Parse XML does not load content properly by repeating title

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating my XML Reader app in which i am trying to parse content from the XDA-Developers site feed. The thing is that it keeps repeating the 1st line and also it gives me some errors.

I am using this [sample](https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/XMLParsingSAXDemo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/pcsalt/example/xmlparsingsaxdemo). The link from the example works perfectly but when i put my link it gives me an error sometimes.

My XMLParser:

```
public class XMLParserXDA extends DefaultHandler{

    private String URL_MAIN = "http://www.xda-developers.com/feed/?format=xml";
    String TAG = "XMLHelper";

    Boolean currTag = false;
    String currTagVal = "";
    private XDAObject post = null;
    private ArrayList<XDAObject> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<XDAObject> getPostsList() {
        return this.posts;
    }

    public void get() {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader();
            mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
            InputStream mInputStream = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();
            mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if (currTag) {
            currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
            currTag = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        currTag = false;

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            post.setTitle(currTagVal);
        }

        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
            post.setDescription(currTagVal);
        }

        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("guid")) {
            post.setGuid(currTagVal);
        }

        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            posts.add(post);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                             Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Log.i(TAG, "START TAG: " + localName);

        currTag = true;
        currTagVal = "";
        if (localName.equals("item"))
            post = new XDAObject();
    }

}
```

The problemm is here:

```
01-13 20:22:08.049    4274-4294/com.kostas.myapplication I/XMLHelper﹕ START TAG: rss
01-13 20:22:08.049    4274-4294/com.kostas.myapplication I/XMLHelper﹕ START TAG: channel
01-13 20:22:08.049    4274-4294/com.kostas.myapplication I/XMLHelper﹕ START TAG: title
01-13 20:22:08.052    4274-4294/com.kostas.myapplication E/XMLHelper﹕ Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void activityobjects.XDAObject.setTitle(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
01-13 20:22:09.103    4274-4289/com.kostas.myapplication W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-13 20:22:09.103    4274-4289/com.kostas.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa36c8e80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-13 20:22:09.180    4274-4274/com.kostas.myapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-13 20:22:12.469    4274-4274/com.kostas.myapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 197 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

And the XDAObject class is:

```
public class XDAObject {
    private String title = null;
    private String guid = "";
    private String description = "";
    private String content = "";


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String link) {
        this.guid = link;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should modify this:

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                             Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Log.i(TAG, "START TAG: " + localName);

        currTag = true;
        currTagVal = "";
        if (localName.equals("title"))
            post = new XDAObject();
    }
```

The title is the starting tag and not the item i had.

Answer (score 0):

currtagval = "" = nothing as a String and override methode characters with parameters no were being used

so currtagval = currtagval + characters(intchar[] ch, int start, int length)

=

currtagvall = "" + unused method ==> null?